# How can I get the compilation time in Flash Builder?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, performance, compilation, flash-builder

Is there a simple way to report the time necessary to compile an applcation in Flash Builder (in the Console or an external file) ?

I want to compare the average compilation time between the usual Flex compiler and HFCD (HellFire Compiler Daemon) for a given project.

Comment: Wow, really great idea. especially on macbook :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `-benchmark=true` to the compiler options to get detailed info on compile times.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_14.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to measure the compilation time by using the Flex ant task.

see [HFCD Ant Tasks Outperform Adobe Flex Ant Tasks](http://stopcoding.wordpress.com/2010/01/29/hfcd-ant-tasks-outperform-adobe-flex-ant-tasks/)